# Getting WebDriver Exception on firefox while going through links on a webpage - Firefox Web Browser

Tags: java, exception, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click links located on a webpage. The webpage is `http://data.worldbank.org/income-level/HIC`. Using Firefox

Consider my following implementation:

```
//This locates all the countries that I need to click on the page.
By countryList = By.cssSelector("a[href*='data.worldbank.org/country/']");

public void retrieveCountryData() throws Exception{
        List<WebElement> countryLinks = driver.findElements(countryList);
        for(int i = 0;i<4;i++){
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            countryLinks.get(i).click();
            System.out.println("The Country is: "+ countryLinks.get(i).getText());
            driver.navigate().back();
        }
    }
```

For testing purpose, I am trying to go through first 4 countries in the list.

When I run my script, it gives me following WebDriverException.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (236.5, 9.5). Other element would receive the click: <a href="http://beta.data.worldbank.org"></a>
Command duration or timeout: 87 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-HQKROAN', ip: '192.168.0.11', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_73'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=46.0, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 1b28ee66-df0a-4885-b937-08dc061675ea
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:85)
    at pageObjects.WorldBankData.retrieveCountryData(WorldBankData.java:163)
    at testCases.SampleTest.getCTex(SampleTest.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:112)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:176)
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here. You can check the HTML of the webpage on your end. Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing Firefox is scrolling down to the country link and then the link is behind the blue banner at the top and can't be clicked.

Comment: How can I make it work?

Comment: You will have to incorporate scrolling to element (to center) before every click.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after loading ur website, use  the code below:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60); 

List<WebElement> countryLinks1 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/country/']"));
int size = countryLinks1.size();

for(int i = 0;i<size;i++){

            List<WebElement> countryLinks = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/country/']"));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/country/']")));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            WebElement elem =countryLinks.get(i);

            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            //this line will scroll to element.
            js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(" + elem.getLocation().x + "," +(elem.getLocation().y- 100) + ");");

            System.out.println("The Country is: "+ elem.getText());
            elem.click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.navigate().back();


        }
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: What if I want to run my for loop for the size of list.
When I initialize my list outside for loop, then my script fails after only one run.

Comment: When you change the page you lose the reference to that element since it will not be in the DOM anymore. An easy way around this is to always get the anchors again after going back to the page. i have already updated my code and first take the size and store it in a variable.